# Chromium v79 graphics rendering freezes unpredictably on Ubuntu 18

Tags: ubuntu, rendering, chromium, freeze

I'm developing an application using HTML and Javascript. The application is supposed to execute and close remote processes.

I'm using Chromium 79.0.3945.79 Built on Ubuntu 18.04.

My application is running in the window of Chromium. 
Some seconds (unpredictable: could be either 5s or 50s) after executing the application, it's like if it is freezed, because the GUI is not "graphically" responding, but in reality it's not freezed because if I press the buttons in the window, the remote processes are executed/terminated (even if I don't see the animation of the mouseover/click on the button). After a while, everything works fine.
To me, it seems like if the rendering of the Chromium windows is hanging, because everything in the background is working and only the graphics is not responding.
In the dev tools there isn't any error.

One strange thing I've noticed is that if I run the Chrome's Task Manager (*Shift+Esc*), the problem never appears and everything works perfectly.

I have the same problem when I run a window of Chromium launching `chromium-browser` from the terminal and navigating in the Settings menu, for example (so, the problem is not my application).

I've already tried to disable some settings like the hardware/gpu acceleration, either from the settings or from the terminal (`--disable-gpu`), but the problem remains.
Also, RAM and CPU usages are low.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was raised in https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/23283471 and the problem on Linux is being investigated in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1036742